# OpenMP and memory limitation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-management, openmp

I have a c++ application that uses openmp parallel construct.

The method inside the for loop uses a lot of memory. It allocates memory at start and release them at the end.

If the system has enough memory, it works well, but if there is not enough memory, the operation fails.

The target system may have enough memory so only 2 thread can be run in parallel or maybe 3 thread can be run in parallel.

Is there any way to configure openmp so it does know how many thread it should use based on available memory?

If OpenMP can no do this, is there any way that I can do this by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenMP is very dumb when it comes to monitoring memory usage and you would have to implement it by yourself. A good strategy would be to obtain the amount of usable memory and then to divide it by the memory requirement per thread in order to get the upper limit of the number of threads that can process data concurrently. Once you know that number, you could force the `parallel` region to run with that many threads using the `num_threads` clause:

```
int max_threads = mem_size / mem_per_thread;

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(max_threads)
for (...)
{
}
```

Now the hard question is how to obtain the amount of usable memory, especially given that virtually all modern operating systems implement virtual memory. One solution would be to leave that to the end user, e.g. provide a parameter in your program's configuration that the user can set to a specific value that he deems reasonable. Another strategy could be to set the value to a given % of the physical memory size.